# What difference between boost awaitable/coroutine/deferred?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++20, boost-coroutine

Can someone explain difference between boost awaitable/coroutine/deferred operations?

As I get all of them do same thing in general.

But for what purposes do we have this separations?

Comment: It will help if you specify exactly what you refer to with the three names. As it stands, `boost::awaitable` cannot be used outside the context of a c++20 `coroutine` at all (so it's hard to see how you feel "they do the same thing"), and `deferred` is a completion token, which quite clearly isn't related to coroutines.

Comment: @sehe, ok, I understand deferred - it just operation without suspension/continuation. But I still don't get difference between awaitable (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/cpp20_coroutines.html - top code part)  and coroutine (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/coro.html - top code part). Both can be suspended/resumed/spawned. What difference?